# Long running Script

Tags: php, wordpress, timeout

I am developing a plugin for wordpress that imports a boatload of data via multiple API calls and saves it as products on woocommerce.

Problem is when a store has hundreds (if not thousands) of products it starts taking a toll on the length of the importing job, resulting in a large variety of timeouts. Extending the import with command like "set_time_limit(xx)" works but some servers still appear to have their own fail-safes that I don't think I can bypass with a line of code:

```
mod_zfpm(63616:7f14fca1b730:0)-F030E35B: stderr: Timeout (900s) exceeded while reading from socket (application) (fastcgi.c:941)'
```

I am trying to figure out which method is the most correct. 
So far the options I have thought of are:

1. use "register_shutdown_function()" on error to relaunch the import (probably a very bad idea)
2. divide the job into a chain of small cron jobs (safer alternative but probably time-consuming and convoluted)

Should I go with option 2 or are there better ways of handling a very long running tasks?

NOTE: Since its a plugin for WP, I cannot employ the solutions suggested in many of the duplicate threads, as the plugin will be used on many different servers.

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to php also but i once came across something like this but the situation was not exactly the same, the solution used was

1) putting the data in JSON format.

2) it was an sql data base the requests were made with Ajax

3) the requests were made in sets depending on the amount of data that needed to be displayed

4) an extra perimeter in the request caused it to return all data with an offset then if data is returned offset is increased and another request is made and second set of returned data is appended to the first set

5) while the the array of data is update asynchronously a JavaScript event listener is attached to reload display when data change's

While this answer won't solve your problem i hope it gives you an idea.